# Can checkboxes be set to "checked" when using wp_set_object_terms?

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm using PHP to pull values from arrays in an API and add them to custom taxonomy within custom post types in Wordpress.

```
  $game_tags = array(
  $games['tags'][0]['name'],
  $games['tags'][1]['name'],
  $games['tags'][2]['name'],
    );

  $term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $games_slug, $game_tags, 'tags_list', true );
```

All works okay, and the custom taxonomy 'tags_list' is populated with the values of $game_tags, but all values are unchecked.

Is there a way to automatically check all values while or after they are added?

**EDIT**

By "checked I mean:

When I pull the values/terms from the database and I put them into custom taxonomy they appear on the custom post type posts edit page as tags (shown as checkboxes). So rather than manually adding tags I am able to create tags using the values I chose from the database.

However, when I create the taxonomy terms (tags), shown as checkboxes, using the PHP, when I go to the posts edit screen all the checkboxes are not ticked.

As I am creating many taxonomy terms, for multiple custom taxonomies within many custom post type posts I was hoping to programmatically tick all the checkboxes rather than having to manually tick them.

Sorry my explanation isn't very good, as I'm still pretty new to PHP.

Comment: By checked do you mean validated, sanitized ?

Comment: that frontend which is using JS DOM in your case. not php.

Comment: @ChrisMedina I've edited the post. By checked I mean the checkboxes created for each taxonomy term (created by the PHP code above) is not automatically ticked/checked within WordPress (on the custom post type Post's edit screen).

Comment: @NMAA I'm not sure what you mean, as I'm quite new to PHP, but I think that by what you are saying, WordPress checkboxes, at least in my case, can't be set to "checked" using PHP? I imagine using JavaScript and jQuery to deal with it would work, but I don't know where to start with that. I'd only want to set the checkboxes of the terms I added from the API to checked, and not any other checkboxes already within the custom taxonomy.